VSCode extension : programatically opening git diff for specific file (not currently open)
I'm working on a VSCode extension and I need to open the git diff of a file for which I have the full path and/or resource URI.
I have the following vscode.Uri:
{
    "$mid": 1,
    "path": "/d:\\git-skip-demo\\nuxt.config.ts",
    "scheme": "file"
}

(The Uri is valid because I can open the file by calling vscode.open() on it and it works)
I also have the full path:
d:\git-skip-demo\nuxt.config.ts

But none of them work to open the git diff (changes) for the file when I call:
vscode.commands.executeCommand('git.openChange', ___URI_OR_FILENAME_HERE___);

Nothing happens, vscode ignores the call and nothing shows in the dev tools console.
Windows paths and linux path have both been tested, none work.
Any help is greatly appreciated !

This seems to work:
await vscode.commands.executeCommand('git.openChange', { uri: vscode.Uri.file("C:\\Users\\Mark\\OneDrive\\BuildSACC\\workFlow.txt") });

That opens a git diff editor.  Note that nothing is returned from that call.
So you need to use an argument object like { uri: yourURI }.
